# Internet Explorer cannot open sites on Windows 2003

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer

I have a server with Windows Server 2003. I have this issue, I have turned enhanced security off, I lowered all security settings in IE, however I can open only Microsoft Update and Bing, as they were added when I first tried to browse, the popup appeared, asking if I trust the site, and I added it in the list. But now, after I played with enhanced security, if I add a site to trusted list trough IE settings it still does not open.

Here are the trusted sites:

[image: Here are the trusted sites]

Even if I turn enhanced security on this [popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reAhl.png) doesn't appear anymore. And I can only reach the sites, that were added trough this popup. How can I turn this annoying security features off, to browse the Internet? Also I have a program, that uses `wininet` and it is depended on IE, so i need to somehow turn off this annoying security feature, otherwise the program using `wininet` doesn't work at all.

Comment: That looks like IE6 to me.

Answer (score 0):

The last version of Internet Explorer supported on Server 2003 is IE8 and it's is badly outdated and unable to display most modern websites. This is not something you can fix by changing settings; the browser simply won't work on such sites.

As a workaround you can install an older version of Firefox (I'm not certain what the latest version is that will run on Server 2003, but you can still download versions that will work). It's also possible some older versions of Chrome will work.

Comment: This is not the case of the issue, because i cannot open the sites other than the trusted inside ie using programming interface `wininet.dll` which works on a http protocol level. Wininet uses preconfigured IE settings too, this is why i'm looking for a way to disable this trusted sites feature completely

Comment: I can't speak to the functionality exposed through the wininet.dll, but I am certain that anything that depends on IE8 will be negatively effected. For example the latest version of TLS supported on Server 2003/IE 8 is TLS 1.0. It sounds like installing another browser won't work though. Sorry.

Comment: @JkDoe2 what about [uninstalling enhanced security configuration](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/how-to-turn-off-ie-enhanced-security-configuration/)?

Comment: yes i have done that step, i unistalled this feature, and for some reason i have this still same effect

Comment: @JkDoe2 perhaps try installing IE8? You could also try a different user account, as all these settings are per-user.

Comment: i just tried, i managed to install only IE7. After installing it, the same behaviour is still observed for some reason

Comment: @JkDoe2 did you try another account?

Comment: created new user called `test` logged into account, and triead to open google with ie, still have the same effect

Comment: Then I don't find good evidence the problem is the security settings. As I noted before, these are per-user settings. Something else is wrong. I really feel the cause is the version of IE and the protocols it doesn't support.

Answer (score 0):

The IE is too outdated, you cant do much there. But you can install older versions of Opera or Firefox wich can still run modern website and with a little effort you can use internet as normal.
I have a Windows 98 computer and had to do this, probably 2003 has a wider support so you might be able to use newer software maybe.
I suggest Firefox 2.0.020 but you can chceck If newer works as well. 
Many websites like Youtube and others require Flash player plugin...version 10 from 2007 should work fine..
But recently lot of web pages (especialy Google sites like Drive and Youtube) dont support majority of old browsers. But there is a plugin called User Agent Switcher for Firefox wich would make your  browser display to the site like a different one (you chose wich) so you should have no problems with that.
Hope it works!